# Performance hit when Ldloca instruction exists in method

Tags: c#, .net, performance, optimization, cil

I ran into a very strange behavior, and I was hoping someone could shed some light on the issue:

```
class Sample
{
    public static void Main()
    {
        const int COUNT = 10000000;
        while (true)
        {
            // move allocation here to allocate more often so more probably to get 50x slowdown problem
            var stopwatch = Stopwatch.StartNew();
            var total = 0;
            for (int i = 1; i <= COUNT; ++i)
            {
                total += i;
            }
            Console.Write("{0}, ", stopwatch.ElapsedMilliseconds);
            if (total > total + 1)
                Console.WriteLine(((object)total).ToString());
        }
    }
}
```

Note the cast to object in the last line (which incidentally will never run). Without it, the code takes a pretty significant performance hit - on my MacBook Pro 15" 2012 running Windows 7 with .NET 4.5 in release, it adds a 16ms overhead, while the running time without the overhead when the total variable is an int is 3ms, or 11ms if it's a double.

The only difference I can see in ILDASM seems to be an added Ldloca instruction - could it be that the existence of this instruction affects the memory layout somehow?

Comment: Reproduced here. I get 18 ms without the cast, 2 ms with it. If I remove the entire line under the `if`, I also get 2 ms.

Comment: Not sure but I did read up a bit on LODLOCA, seems to push something on the stack..  Perhaps it has something to do with this: if (total > total + 1)

Comment: You have to look at the machine code to see the difference.  The fast version keeps *total* in a CPU register, the slow one keeps it in memory.  Memory is slow.  Bit of a flaw in the optimizer, oddly the x64 jitter does it as well.  Not much you can do about it.